# Displaying data from one database table without using id and objects.all()

Tags: python, html, django

I want to display some of the field values from the member table (fullname, email, contactno, companyname etc..,) in the profile page fieldset.

---

models.py for member table

```
class Member(models.Model):
   fullname=models.CharField(max_length=30)
   companyname=models.CharField(max_length=30)
   Email=models.CharField(max_length=50)
   password=models.CharField(max_length=12)
   contactno = models.CharField(max_length=30,default='anything')
```

---

models.py for profile table.

```
class Profile(models.Model):
   fullname=models.CharField(max_length=60)
   contactno=models.CharField(max_length=10)
   worknumber=models.CharField(max_length=10)
   email=models.CharField(max_length=30)
   companyname=models.CharField(max_length=30)
   timezone=models.CharField(max_length=20)
```

---

Here is the profile page, the data should be displayed automatically:

[image: here is the profile page, the data should be displayed automatically]

Answer (score 0):

I assume it's better to change the data model design.You can make a relation between Member and Profile since each member should have one profile(generally).
Add a OneToOne relation in Profile model to Member model;Then you can access related member details in profile page.